# dpkg: "Package is in a very bad inconsistent state" how to fix it?

Tags: apt, dpkg

When I run command

```
sudo apt-get -f
```

I get this error

```
dpkg: error processing gcc-4.8-base:i386 (--configure):
Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
reinstall it before attempting configuration.
Errors were encountered while processing:
gcc-4.8-base:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 3):

> Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - **you should
>   reinstall it** before attempting configuration.

You have to reinstall the package:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gcc-4.8-base:i386
```

Comment: when i run that command , i will get this


se (= 4.8.1-10ubuntu8) but 4.8.1-10ubuntu9 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: @AwisQirani edit your question, I can't read anything.

Answer (score 1):

I tried both of the answers given above at last after a lot of struggle i found this

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all gcc-4.8-base:i386
```

if somebody else is looking at this answer for another package then just replace `gcc-4.8-base:i386` with the name of the package causing trouble

even after this if your problem is not solved then find all the files named with your package name as a prefix and use

```
sudo chmod 777 filename
```

with all of them and then create a copy of them (in case something goes wrong) and then use

```
sudo rm filename
```

to delete of them and then run this again

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all gcc-4.8-base:i386
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually the problem is related to gcc 4.8 ,use the following to solve this issue -

Remove gcc-

```
sudo apt-get purge gcc-4.8
```

now check -

```
sudo apt-get -f
```

for correcting all broken downloads.

Add repository-

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
```

install again -

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
```

hope it will work.