How to fix the install management system on Ubuntu 24, after it's been broken due to an incomplete installation of zoom (.deb)?
Following an incomplete installation of zoom through the official amd64 .deb file,the gdebi kept asking me to fix it when I used it for another install or when it came up for an update.

The package zoom must be reinstalled but I can't find an archive for
it.

(I did not delete the downloaded deb file.)
I tried to remove the program but it can't be (since I always get the above message before the process stops). clean and reinstall won't do anything.
After that, another message came up, telling me the software index had been corrupted. I checked the sources.list file as asked but it's been left unchanged for two months (and is fully readable). sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install-f also stop as soon as they're reading the "state informations", before I'm told again that zoom must be reinstalled.
I decided to resort to dpkg but this is what I got:

sudo dpkg --purge zoom dpkg: process error for zoom package
(--purge) :  the package must be in an incoherent state : you should
reinstall it before trying to delete it. Errors happened during the
execution : zoom

(Sorry for the approximate translation.)
Laptop computer: ASUS E402NA, Intel® Pentium® N4200×4
Linux: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, noyau 6.8.0-1017-oem
Another thread with a similar situation but different error messages: How to fix fix broken install command (due to zoom installation)

So have you tried to reinstall the downloaded deb-package( sudo apt reinstall /path/to/zoom_amd64.deb)?

@mook765 I did. It did the same thing as with all later attempts to install/remove something:
"E: The zoom package must be reinstalled but it is impossible to find its archive."
Idem with a redownloaded copy.

Take a look at the second answer here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/383804/dpkg-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-how-to-fix-it  
And recovery here.
https://thelinuxcode.com/fix-broken-ubuntu-22-04-without-reinstalling/
All the following is AT YOUR OWN RISK.
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all [Your package name]

If your problem is not solved then find all the files named with your package name as a prefix and use
sudo chmod 777 filename

and then use
sudo rm filename

And then try again.

After it hopefuly works you will want to restore you system: -
apt update -m  
dpkg --configure -a
apt install -f

And finally
apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

Good luck.
